# How to get multiple Mirror Maker nodes to divide the replication load?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am trying to enable replication between two different Kafka clusters (cluster A and cluster B). I do not require active/active replication. Going from A → B is enough for me.

To achieve that goal I plan to set up a Mirror Maker 2 cluster such as data flows as follows:

cluster A → Mirror Maker 2 cluster → cluster B

Cluster A has close to 3k partitions and it is part of a business-critical application so I have to guarantee speedy replication between A and B.

I started experimenting with setting up a dedicated mirror maker cluster (i.e. using `connect-mirror-maker.sh`).

[KIP-382](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0#KIP382:MirrorMaker2.0-RunningadedicatedMirrorMakercluster) mentions that “In this mode, MirrorMaker does not require an existing Connect cluster. Instead, a high-level driver manages a collection of Connect workers.”. However, I am struggling with how to make multiple nodes communicate amongst themselves to divide up the load.

I have tried multiple configs such as `listeners`, `rest.advertised.host.name`, `rest.advertised.port`, and others.

None of them seem to enable communication between MM2 workers. Can someone point me to an example configuration on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

After digging a little into this I've found out that as of now (June/2022) there's no support for distributed mode in for the dedicated Mirror Maker cluster. If one wants to run Mirror Maker with multiple agents/workers, a connect cluster is needed.
There's a [KIP under consideration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-710%3A+Full+support+for+distributed+mode+in+dedicated+MirrorMaker+2.0+clusters) to change this behaviour.